# Convergence of $\frac{\sinh^2(x)}{\sinh^2(x) + C}$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, hyperbolic-functions

I was wondering if someone could help me conclude what happens when I set $x\rightarrow\infty$ for the following equation where $C\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sinh^2(x)}{\sinh^2(x) + C}$$

I just do not know where to go with this. It is related to a physics problem I am doing.

Comment: The title and the question in the main body seem quite different.

Comment: What identities occur when $C=1$?

Comment: Write it as $1-....$

Comment: @AdiDani: People should not edit when their edit totally ruins the question.

Comment: I have not change anything

Comment: sorry all for the confusion. I indeed intented to write $\sinh$ in the title. Thank you @Ted Shifrin for respecting my words though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\sinh^2(x)=\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2 \right)^2 \sim \frac{e^{2x}}4
$$ giving, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\sinh^2(x)}{\sinh^2(x) + C}=\frac1{1 +\frac{C}{\sinh^2(x)}}\sim \frac1{1 +\frac{4C}{e^{2x}}} \to 1.
$$

Comment: And if the question is really about $\text{sech}(x)$, then $\text{sech}(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, so it's even simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that

$$\frac{\sinh^2(x)}{\sinh^2(x)+C}=\frac{\sinh^2(x)+C-C}{\sinh^2(x)+C}\\=1-\frac C{\sinh^2(x)+C}$$

And then the limit is hopefully more clear.

Comment: What is the limit of $\sinh^2(x)$ as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Diverges to $+\infty$ silly, so the fraction goes to...?

Comment: How do you prove it diverges to $\infty$?

Comment: $\sinh x \rightarrow \infty, x \rightarrow \infty$, so also the square diverges.